# Expression must be a list type error?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have the following code:

```
public class Testcode {


private static final Long[] P = new Long[18];


 public void setKey( string key )
{
integer i, j, k;
long data;
integer N = 16;
string[] keytemp = new string[]{};
keytemp.add(key);

// Initialize P and S.
for ( i = 0; i < N + 2; ++i ){
    P[i] = Pinit[i];
    }

  // XOR the key into P.
j = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < N + 2; ++i )
    {
    data = 0;
    for ( k = 0; k < 4; ++k )
    {
   data = ( data << 8 ) | keytemp[j];
    ++j;
    }
    P[i] ^= data;
    }   

}    

    private static final long[] Pinit = new Long[] {
   604135516L,   2242044355L,  320440478L ,  57401183L,
    2732047618L,  698298832L,   137296536L ,  3964563569L,
    1163258022L,  954160567L,   3193502383L,  887688400L,
    3234508543L,  3380367581L,  1065660069L,  3041631479L,
    2420952273L,  2306437331L 
   };   
}
```

im getting the following error:

Error: Compile Error: OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions or to Integer or Long expressions at line 36 column 18

which is in this line:

```
data = ( data << 8 ) | keytemp[j];
```

Is there another way to write this line of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the j-th bit in key variable? I don't think Apex supports syntax like that (with indexes). `[]` operator is reserved for arrays so that's the error you get.

In fact it's not even an operator I think (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm), just a shortcut to write `myList.get(index)`.

Try the shifting trick again?

```
Long key = 255;

System.debug(key & (1 << 7));   // 128
System.debug(key & (1 << 8));   // 0
```

Comment: Ok I made a mistake, key has to be a string, so & or | doesn't work with strings, not sure what to use!, any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my original posting, and I have a different error, this line of code is expectable in Java, because I can define key as a byte, but I can't do that here. is there another way to write this line of code?